# Как задать определить каждую десятую итерацию в цикле?

Tags: javascript, jquery

надо реализовать для каждой десятой итерации в цикле некоторую логику, например есть следующий код:

```
for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
  if(...){
    console.log('Good');
  }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста в этой небольшой задаче

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) {
    console.log('Good: ', i);
  }
}
```

```js
for (var i = 9; i < 100; i = i + 10) {
  console.log('Good: ', i);
}
```

Comment: Отличные решения, спасибо большое

Comment: @NikolayMuravets На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 1):

Можно поменять начальное значение переменной цикла, чтобы начинало считать с `1`. Затем вы получите то что хотели.

```
if(i >= 10 && i%10 == 0){
  console.log('Good');
}
```